# Apply Migration Scripts on docker startup

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, database-migration

I am Unable to initialise database with schema evolution manager on docker startup. My docker file is as follows

```
FROM postgres:10-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/ext-api-db
COPY . .

RUN apk add py-pip ruby ruby-rdoc
RUN gem install schema-evolution-manager && \
    pip install awscli

RUN cp docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 5432
```

docker-entrypoint-initdb.d contain one init script

```
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE ${POSTGRES_USER}_test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ${POSTGRES_USER}_test TO $POSTGRES_USER;
EOSQL

# Applying Sem Scripts
echo
echo 'PostgreSQL initialzing Data...'
echo

"pg_ctl -o" -c listen_addresses='localhost'" -D "$PGDATA" -w restart"

sem-apply --url postgresql://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@localhost/$POSTGRES_DB
sem-apply --url postgresql://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@localhost/$POSTGRES_DB_test
```

On docker container startup the database is created fine but the schema evolution manager says its unable to connect to database 
Here is the complete stack trace

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
CREATE DATABASE
GRANT

PostgreSQL initialzing Data...

psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Address not available
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/lib/schema-evolution-manager/library.rb:136:in `rescue in system_or_error': Error running command[psql --no-align --tuples-only --no-psqlrc --command "select count(*) from pg_namespace where nspname='schema_evolution_manager'" postgresql://user:pass@localhost/db]: Non zero exit code[pid 47 exit 2] running command[psql --no-align --tuples-only --no-psqlrc --command "select count(*) from pg_namespace where nspname='schema_evolution_manager'" postgresql://user:pass@localhost/db] (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/lib/schema-evolution-manager/library.rb:129:in `system_or_error'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/lib/schema-evolution-manager/db.rb:32:in `psql_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/lib/schema-evolution-manager/db.rb:90:in `schema_schema_evolution_manager_exists?'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/lib/schema-evolution-manager/scripts.rb:86:in `scripts_previously_run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/lib/schema-evolution-manager/scripts.rb:48:in `each_pending'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/lib/schema-evolution-manager/db.rb:22:in `bootstrap!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/schema-evolution-manager-0.9.39/bin/sem-apply:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/sem-apply:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/sem-apply:23:in `<main>'
```

Here is my docker-compose config

```
version: "3"
services:
  ext-api-db:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: ext-api-db
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    hostname: ext-api-db
    networks:
      - ext
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/ext-api-db:delegated
networks:
  ext:
    external:
      name: ext
```

Can someone tell me how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the docker command you use to run this container?

Comment: I don't use any docker command. Its handled by postgres automatically. it seems like postgres:10-alpine image has its own built in command

Comment: You have a Dockerfile and you start a container from it. Don't you use a docker run?

Comment: @Mihai I use docker-compose. I have updated docker-compose config in my question

Comment: I believe the problem is with PSQL not accepting tcp/ip connections. But for this I would like to know if the command "psql -U $POSTGRES_USER" executes. Can you put an echo after the command and see it shows up in the logs? If it does then we need to check the postgres conf files and look for "listen_addresses" which I would expect to be commented out and it shouldn't. Can you perform these steps and let me know the results? If you need guidance let me know. In any case I really don't think this is a problem with your docker setup

Comment: @MihaiYes i tried echo after that command and i see it printed on console 
My question is if somehow its related to psql the why other psql commands work including the first one where i am creating database

Comment: They work because they connect through socket. The last ones connect on tcp/ip. Can you implement the fix I mentioned?

Comment: @Mihai Okay i am looking into DB config. One thing i noted is if i run these schema evolution commands after docker start up using docker exec -it bash they work fine but not in entrypoint. Does it mean that postgres start TCP IP connections after full docker launch?

Comment: @MihaiI have listen_addresses = '*' set in postgres config

Comment: Yes, that explains why the commands run successfully after. I checked the docker-entrypoint.sh script (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/docker-entrypoint.sh) and I can see that there are some operations done after this script runs. Unfortunately I am not a posgres expert and I don't know what those commands really do (line 165-166). The information you gave me is very important (that it works on docker exec) so i'll try to draw a solution. I will add it as answer because I can format it better there but I can delete it after if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mihai Sure Thanks
I will be looking forward to hear from you soon

Comment: One more thing: could you try and add this line "pg_ctl -o "-c listen_addresses='localhost'" -D "$PGDATA" -w restart" just before the "sem-apply" commands? I don't have your files so I can't try it

Comment: @MihaiIt returns pg_ctl -o -c: command not found

Comment: I am sorry but that's impossible. I tried it and it works. and actually this is the solution since it enables tcp/ip. Can you please check the script again? Maybe post it and I'll check it. Maybe you run on windows and it has different line endings... Plus it is weird that it sees "pg_ctl -o -c" as a whole command. It should only report pg_ctl as missing (IF it was missing, but it's not). You did remove the initial and final quotes in the command, right? So the line starts with pg_ctl

Comment: @MihaiYeah i tried its not working 
Can you send me a full working command ?
I have update entrypoint script with your command in my question so that you can have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entrypoint script should be:

```
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE ${POSTGRES_USER}_test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ${POSTGRES_USER}_test TO $POSTGRES_USER;
EOSQL

# Applying Sem Scripts
echo
echo 'PostgreSQL initialzing Data...'
echo

pg_ctl -o "-c listen_addresses='localhost'" -D "$PGDATA" -w restart

echo Server restarted with TCP/IP enabled

sem-apply --url postgresql://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@localhost/$POSTGRES_DB
sem-apply --url postgresql://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@localhost/$POSTGRES_DB_test
```